# Rails and Devise how skip validation when reset password

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I find myself facing a problem so I doubt I was the only one to have been confronted, but yet I find no solution.

I just added new fields with new validation on my user model. I make sure to redirect old users with an incomplete profile to a form for whom completes it.

My problem is that if an old user has forgotten his password, he can not reset it because when saving the new password the validations fail. then how to make the password reset escape the validations

Comment: Can you post the code

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem, in my case solution was adding if condition:

```
validates :new_field, presence: true, if: -> { !encrypted_password_changed? }
```

on every validation that were causing problems

for more details check:
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/1623
and
https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#conditional-validation

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I have both a presence validator and a custom validator firing on a user model. In certain circumstances one or both would me missing/incorrect causing users not to be able to reset their passwords. You can escape this by looking for the presence of a reset password token (or whatever other Devise param that you anticipate being passed) by using a proc.

```
validates :a_field, presence: true, unless: Proc.new { |u| u.reset_password_token.present? }

validate :custom_validator_method, unless: Proc.new { |u| u.reset_password_token.present? }
```

Comment: I think this should be `reset_password_token`.